# PNG or ICO used as favicon lacks transparency (IE/Edge)

Tags: html, internet-explorer, favicon, microsoft-edge

I've noticed that some favicon's for web-pages (including my own) does not display correctly and transparency is ignored.

For example: [image]

Feel free to test my [web-page](http://bdu.bz/) favicon out using IE/Edge and it will display similar results. I have made sure that transparency has been exported (in the alpha layer) using GIMP. An image is attached below for reference.

[image]

Does anyone see anything wrong with either my header coding for a favicon or an issue with the image?

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="./favicon.ico?v=1.0">
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Edited.. I don't know how I left that out.. @i_am_jorf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue pictured above appears to be a bug for the dark theme of Microsoft Edge, as the favicon shows up as expected on the light theme.

However internet explorer's issue (displaying a document icon underneath the favicon) was resolved by adding the following line of code:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" href="./favicon.ico?v=1.0">
```

Comment: This is a bug in Edge - I have raise an issue internally about it and will update once i get something back from the team that owns this part of the browser.

Answer (score 0):

IE supports ico as favicon, you need to generate an `ico` from your `png` image. IE 11 supports PNG for Favicons.

Comment: I have used both ICO and PNG with no change. See my link and image.